# While Generating XML File from Class non string value getting omitted

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have class Diag [Generated by using xsd tool] and i am generating XML file for the same.

```
Diag diag = new Diag();
                            diag.DiagId = "1";
                            diag.Locked = false;
                            diag.Code = "C90.00";
                            diag.PrimSec = "+";
                            diag.IsTextStd = false;
                            diag.PdxGr = true;
                            diag.NotForGr = false;
                            diag.DiagTypeFlags = "$FHD;$ED;$BD";
                            diag.DeptNum = 0;
                            diag.ModType = "U";
                            diag.Amount=2800;
```

XML format i am getting is like

[image]
I am using  XmlSerializer

```
 XmlSerializer mySerializer = new
                XmlSerializer(typeof(Diag));

    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("myFileName.XML");
    mySerializer.Serialize(writer, diag);
```

I am not getting why non string values are not getting generated in XML?

Comment: Can you post the generated Diag code?  Or a least the definitions of a couple of the problem fields, including all attributes

Comment: Adding two fields for reference

 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int DeptNum {
        get {
            return this.deptNumField;
        }
        set {
            this.deptNumField = value;
        }
    }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool Locked {
        get {
            return this.lockedField;
        }
        set {
            this.lockedField = value;
        }
    }

Comment: To show fields i need to set its specified field to true like to set lockedField i need to set lockedFieldSpecified to true
private bool lockedField;        private bool lockedFieldSpecified;